# querySelector and querySelectorAll alias

Tags: javascript, dom, alias

What is the best unobtrusive alternative to do a cross browser alias for `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` for both `document` and `Element`

The most straight forward way might be

```
window.$ = function(selector){return document.querySelector(selector)}
window.$$ = function(selector){return document.querySelectorAll(selector)}
```

Of course this will not allow chaining as the function return always refers to the `document`

```
$('.parent-class').$$('.child-classes')
```

My best choice so far is

```
window.$ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
window.$$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
Element.prototype.$ = Element.prototype.querySelector;
Element.prototype.$$ = Element.prototype.querySelectorAll;
```

This way we are allowed to do the previous failed selector, although i am not sure about the bad implications that this might bring, does anyone have a hint/explanation that can provide?

Does anyone have a good unobtrusive alternative?

Comment: * as the function return always refers to the document * What does that mean? *  we are allowed to do the previous failed selector, * What does that mean? Anyway, what are you trying to accomplish? Save some keystrokes?

Comment: " as the function return always refers to the document" - Means that in the first example as we have the return of the function with document.qs the result is obviously always refered to the document.

"we are allowed to do the previous failed selector" - Means that the previous failed selector ($('.parent-class').$$('.child-classes')) works chained and with context.

Yes trying to save keystrokes and readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> unobtrusive alternative

Make a wrapper so you don't extend other/native structures, call it something unlikely to conflict

```
var Σ = (function () {
    function Found(nodes) {
        this.nodes = nodes;
    }
    function find(selector) {
        var nodes;
        if (this instanceof Found) {
            nodes = Array.prototype.map.call(this.nodes, e => Array.prototype.slice.call(e.querySelectorAll(selector)));
            nodes = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], nodes);
            return new Found(nodes);
        }
        if (this === window)
            return new Found(Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector)));
        return new Found(Array.prototype.slice.call(this.querySelectorAll(selector)));
    }
    Found.prototype.find = find;
    return find;
}());
```

So you could do something like

```
Σ('.answer').find('pre').nodes;
```

To get all the `<pre>` nodes (which are the code bits) in answers here. You can chain `.find` as much as desired.

---

> cross browser

What is wrong with *jQuery*?

Comment: voting up for cross browser part.

Answer (score 7):

I also use the `bind` approach for creating an alias.

```
var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
var $$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
```

For the element one I use a function and `apply` so that it will behave exactly as if you called it the "VanillaJS" way.

```
Element.prototype.$ = function() {
  return this.querySelector.apply(this, arguments);
};

Element.prototype.$$ = function() {
  return this.querySelectorAll.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Here's an example:

```js
var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
var $$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);

Element.prototype.$ = function() {
  return this.querySelector.apply(this, arguments);
};

Element.prototype.$$ = function() {
  return this.querySelectorAll.apply(this, arguments);
};

alert($('.foo').innerHTML);
alert('There are ' + $$('.foo').length + ' `.foo` nodes');

var parent = $('.parent');
alert(parent.$('.child').innerText);
alert('There are ' + parent.$$('.child').length + ' children');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class=foo>It works!</div>
  <div class=foo>It worked again!</div>
  <div class=parent>Parent
    <div class=child>Child</div>
    <div class=child>Another Child</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

You'll have to create something quite a bit more elaborate if you'd like chaining. You might want to check out [Bliss](http://blissfuljs.com/) for a lightweight (~3kb) library that supports chaining but is more like VanillaJS than jQuery.

Comment: But your `Element.prototype.$ = function() {
  return this.querySelector.apply(this, arguments);
};` is exactly equivalent to the OP's `Element.prototype.$ = Element.prototype.querySelector;`. Actually, it's subtly different; yours will call a `querySelector` defined directly on the element if one exists.

Answer (score 4):

The best unobtrusive alternative is to **not** do such an alias. It's another thing to remember, it's another thing for people looking at your code to learn, it probably breaks your IDE's autocomplete and syntax checking features, and it pollutes prototypes.

However, if you want to proceed down this path nevertheless, it's going to take special machinery to chain anything from `$$` and `Element.$$`, since they return node lists. First, we will make `$$` return an array:

```
window.$$ = function(sel) { 
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelector(sel)); 
}
```

And the same for `Element.$$`. Now we can augment the `Array` prototype:

```
Array.prototype.$ = function(sel) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    var sub = this[i].querySelector(sel);
    if (sub) result.push(sub);
  }
  return result;
};
```

Go ahead and rewrite this using `map` and/or `filter` etc. if it suits your fancy.

Now you can do:

```
$$('.class1').$('span')
```

Similarly, you could define a version of `$$` on `Array`, as follows:

```
Array.prototype.$$ = function(sel) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    var elts = this[i].querySelectorAll(sel);
    for (var j = 0; j < elts.length; j++) {
      result.push(elts[j]);
    }
  }
  return result;
;
```

This combines all the nodelists resulting from `querySelectorAll` calls on each member of the input nodelist into one single array.

If you want to chain something like `setAttribute`, you'll need to define versions for both `Element` and `Array`:

```
Element.prototype.setAttributeChainable = function() {
  this.setAttribute.apply(this, arguments);
  return this;
}

Array.prototype.setAttributeChainable = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    this[i].setAttribute.apply(this[i], arguments);
  }
  return this;
}
```

To make this fail silently when `$` finds nothing, arrange for it to return an empty array in that case:

```
window.$ = function(sel) {
  return document.querySelector(sel) || [];
};
```

and the same for `Element.$`.

Now you can do

```
$$('.class1') .
  $$('span') .
  setAttributeChainable('style', 'color:blue') .
  $('a') .
  setAttributeChainable('href', 'google.com');
```

Now continue this exercise with any other APIs you want to make chainable and/or applicable to node lists.

If you have religious objections to adding to the `Array` prototype, you'll have to find some other approach.

Comment: Wow, the question asking for opinions got an opinion that the op doesn't like.